# Capybara: expected not to find xpath "/html/body/*", found 3 matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm getting this exception and I can't figure out why.

```
  expected not to find xpath "/html/body/*", found 3 matches: "", "Log in Welcome back Sign up Join the community myproj.com Community curated directory of 0 EVENTS", "". Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters. (Capybara::ExpectationNotMet)
  ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myproj/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:125:in `block in assert_no_selector'
  ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myproj/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:84:in `synchronize'
  ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myproj/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:121:in `assert_no_selector'
  ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myproj/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:686:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
  ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myproj/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:109:in `reset!'
  ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myproj/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara.rb:285:in `block in reset_sessions!'
  ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myproj/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara.rb:285:in `each'
  ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myproj/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara.rb:285:in `reset_sessions!'
  ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myproj/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb:8:in `After'
```

**EDIT:**

I'm using selenium-webdriver (firefox 42.0)

[env.rb](https://gist.github.com/chalmagean/0df965d41bdf88b4c873)

[rails_helper.rb](https://gist.github.com/chalmagean/5944c614ae1aea28be8b)

Comment: Please post all the relevant code, and what you've tried.

Comment: Provide your test, please

Comment: That error means whatever driver you're using with Capybara hasn't cleared the browser (in most cases that means visiting about:blank in the browser) or maybe you've changed Capybara.default_max_wait_time so that the browser doesn't have time to change the page - What driver are you using? and have you modified the drivers session reset! method?

Comment: I've added gists with my env.rb and rails_helper.rb. I'm using selenium-webdriver (firefox 42.0)

Comment: Do you mind adding your test as well?

Comment: Is this only happening for specific tests, or all your tests?  If a specific test, please post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case was that after I would click a link, the page that the link was pointing to didn't get to load before the expectation was run. I had the click and the expectation in two different steps. So by adding an expectation to the step that did the clicking, I was able to fix this (by forcing capybara to wait for the new page to load).

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue. what i've done to solve it, it's to add visit 'about:blank' in the last line of the test case.

ie:

```
it 'testing search functionality...' do
   visit '/'
   fill_in('search_id', with: 'tablet')
   click_link 'Search'
   expect(page).to have_content 'tablet'

   visit 'about:blank'  #<-- this flashes page body (the buffer 
                        #    of the last page) and that's it
end
```

good luck :)